# Is there a differentiable function $ f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$, $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1+i$, and $(f'(x))^2 \in\mathbb R$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

But I found that there is no such example. According to the question, let $f(x)=u(x)+iv(x)$ where $u,v$ are both differentiable function.By GMVT, for any $x\in [0,1]$, we have: $$\frac{u'}{v'}=\frac{u(1)-u(0)}{v(1)-v(0)}=1.$$

But since $(f'(x))^2 \in\mathbb R$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, for $x\in [0,1]$, we have $$f'(x)=u'+iv' \implies (f')^2=(u')^2+2u'v'i-(v')^2=2(u')^2i.$$ So only when $u'=v'=0$ can $(f')^2 \in\mathbb R$. So $u$ $v$ are both constant, then we cannot have $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1+i$.

I am really confused now. Is there something wrong with my understanding?

Comment: From the GMVT, it says that there **exists** a $c \in [0,1]$ such that $u' = v'$. It is **not** true for any $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: oh, yes! Thank you so much.

Comment: Your problem essentially boils down to: "Let $f, g$ be differentiable functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb {R} $ such that $f(0)=g(0)=0,f(1)=g(1)=1$. Is there is a point $c\in[0,1]$ such that $f'(c) g'(c) \neq 0$?"

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f'(x)$ is either real or pure imaginary. So we can get to $1+i$ in two steps: first, move in the positive real direction to get to $f(\tfrac12)=1$, then move in the positive imaginary direction to add the extra $i$.

Your notation has led you astray. While it is true (by a mean value theorem) that there exists $x\in [0,1]$ for which $u'(x)=v'(x)$, it is not true that $u'(x)=v'(x)$ for all $x$.

Anyway, you can consider $f'(x)$ defined piecewise continuous as follows:
$$
f'(x)=\begin{cases}24x(1-2x),&x\in[0,\tfrac12]\\24(2x-1)(1-x)i,&x\in[\tfrac12,1]\end{cases}
$$
which satisfies the conditions. By integrating, you will find that $f(1)-f(0)=1+i$ as desired.

Comment: How does address the problem, as written in the body?

Comment: The question was edited as I was starting to write my answer, which I am continuing to write. However, it clearly addresses the question, since the conclusion $u'=v'=0$ is false. I am writing up an example...

Comment: Looking through the edit history, none of the edits have changed the body, other than bolding $R$ to $\mathbb R$. I know since I was editing :)